# How do I update a getJSON url dynamically using an jQuery call?

Tags: jquery, getjson

I am working on a modal flow to gather information from a user. The first url is /choose-setting, the second is /choose-language. Upon clicking the Next button a request is made to the first url which passes back the content and form for the second question, choose a language, and finally it updates the the getJSON url so upon clicking Next again it makes a request for the 3rd question, so an so forth.

In the snippet below my php sends back an array with the new javascript to replace the content in the script  tag---using javascript to update itself.

In the dev console (Chrome) when I click on the Next button it shows that the second url is being called as expected, then it calls the first url again for some reason. Moreover, the modal content from the /choose-language url does not replace the /choose-setting content.

One, is my technique a sound approach? Two, if it is, what is happening and how do I get to the expected behavior?

Thank you.

```
<div id="btn-jscript">
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#nextBtn").click(function(){
$.getJSON("/event/create/modal/choose-setting", function(content){
   $("#modal-label").replaceWith(content.header);
   $("#form-content").replaceWith(content.body);
   $("#btn-jscript").replaceWith(content.jscript);
  });
 }); 
});   
</script> 
</div>
```

[dev console showing the unexpected behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPkWz.png)

Comment: Please add a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/) which shows the actual problem.

Comment: Create a JSFiddle with an example...